# Binding to a sub-property and updating if any property in chain has changed

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

While learning MVVM, I've created a `DataTemplate` for one of my view models:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type task:NodeDefinitionVM}">
    <Ellipse Width="4" Height="4" Fill="Red" >
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Location.X, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                Y="{Binding Location.Y, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    </Ellipse>
</DataTemplate>
```

Simplified view model class:

```
class NodeDefinitionVM : (...)
{
    public Point Location
    {
        get { return model.Location; }
        set { model.Location = value; }
    }
(...)
}
```

In my case the model implements INotifyPropertyChanged, because I need to have all changes to model reflected in View (notice `Mode=TwoWay` in XAML).

**Problem:** Initial values of transform offsets (X, Y) are set and I get notifications when '*Location*' property changes. However there is *no* notification that **.X** has changed and, as I'm binding to Location.X, the transform is not updated (except for the first time), because it expects Location.X change notification. The `Point` type is a light-weight *struct*.

**Question:** Is it possible to bind to .X, while updating the binding whenever any of the properties along **Location.X** chain changes? Is there a general solution for a 'longer chain' like `Binding prop1.prop2.prop3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strangely enough, binding directly to X or Y properties of a TranslateTransform won't work well, although these are DependencyProperties. Following modifications made it work:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type task:NodeDefinitionVM}">
    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Width="4" Height="4" Fill="Red" 
             RenderTransform="{Binding TranslateMatrix}">
    </Ellipse>
</DataTemplate>
```

I needed to create a new '`TranslateMatrix`' property in my ViewModel:

```
    public TranslateTransform TranslateMatrix
    {
        get
        {
            var tt = new TranslateTransform(model.Location.X, model.Location.Y);
            return tt;
        }
    }
```

Finally, the VM needs to publish notifications that the `TranslateMatrix` property changes every time `Location` the property changes. So the VM listens to model changes and notifies if necessary:

```
    void NodeDefinitionVM_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Location")
            NotifyPropertyChanged(() => TranslateMatrix);
    }
```

Comment: THANKYOU! Stumbled across your answer and it's the only one on this page to solve my problem. <3

Answer (score 2):

In general, the binding should update when any property in the chain changes. But this works only when each property in the chain raises `PropertyChanged` properly, because there is no way to figure out that something changed otherwise.

For this to work, you would need either to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `Point` and raise `PropertyChanged` when `X` or `Y` changes, or you need to raise the event for `Location` when that happens.

Comment: In fact, there is no way to change X or Y only, since Location is a ValueType property on the model. So the only way is to do: model.Location = new Point(...). So the whole Location changes and notifies. Now I suppose the problem is the 'TranslateTransform', which is not a FrameworkElement (has no DataContext). WPF outputs an error: "Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element". I have no idea what's the work-around though. Especially that the binding works initially.

Comment: You can change `X` only. `model.Location.X = 42` should work (unless `Point` is read-only, which it really should be – mutable structs are bad thing). When does it output that error?

Comment: You can't do it, when `Location` is a *ValueType property*. `model.Location` part of this assignment will make a local Point copy. `model.Location.X = 42` would change X on that copy. This won't even compile.

Comment: This error is shown in Output Window in VS after running the app.

Comment: @rook, no, it won't make a copy and it will work, if `Point` is mutable.

Comment: what you say is only true if `Location` is a *field*. For properties it's not. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wydkhw2c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no way achieve what you're talking about, as much as I'm aware of and met till now in my WPF experience.

As assigning the `X`, you jump over actual property.

So you need manually notify do Binding mechanism that property was changed, but how you're gonna figure out that property was changed in your example, if you directly gonna assign value to public *field* of the struct ?

Regards.

Comment: The thing is that neither X nor Y will be modified directly, because they are properties not fields. So I can't do e.g. "model.Location.X = number". The Location is set as a whole: "Location = new Point()". I'm starting to believe it's a problem about RenderTransform.